Laravel login is stuck in an endless loop when the 1Password browser plugin is active
I received a problem report from a user. For them, the login page keeps loading endlessly. Upon closer inspection, I was able to reproduce it with the 1Password plugin. It seems to attempt to log in the user and redirect directly to Home, resulting in continuous switching between /home and /login. The home route is secured with the Auth middleware.
No form is being submitted, as the login opens in a popup.
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import {Head, usePage} from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import Auth from '../Layouts/Auth.vue'
import ActionButton from '../Components/Buttons/LoungeActionButton.vue'

const isLoading = ref(false)
const page = usePage()

const login = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true
    const newWindow = openWindow({
        title: 'Login',
        url: page.props.auth.oauth_url
    })

    if (!newWindow) {
        alert("The pop-up was blocked by your browser. Please allow popups for this website.");
        isLoading.value = false;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    if (e.origin !== window.origin) return;
    location.href = route('test.home');
    isLoading.value = false;
}, {once: true});

function openWindow({url = '', title = '', width = 600, height = 720} = {}) {
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || screen.width;
    const screenHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || screen.height;
    const left = (screenWidth - width) / 2 + window.screenLeft ?? window.screen.left;
    const top = (screenHeight - height) / 2 + window.screenTop ?? window.screen.top;
    const optionsStr = `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`;

    return window.open(url, title, optionsStr);
}
</script>


<template>
    <Head title="Login"></Head>

    <Auth>
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="text-3xl font-medium text-[#0053a0] dark:text-[#3493eb]">
                {{ $t('app.name') }}
            </h1>

            <p class="mb-4 font-light">
                {{ $t('For team and network members') }}
            </p>

            <ActionButton class="w-80" :disabled="isLoading" @click="login">
                {{ $t('Log in with your Member ID') }}
            </ActionButton>

            <div class="mt-12">
                <a href="https://legacy.iza.org/conference_files/formLogin"
                   class="inline-flex items-center text-sm text-slate-400 dark:text-slate-500 pb-[3px] px-1 border-b border-transparent hover:border-slate-400 dark:hover:border-slate-600 hover:text-[#39c] dark:hover:text-[#3493eb] transition duration-200 ease-in-out"
                >
                    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'right-to-bracket']" class="mr-1" aria-hidden="true"/>

                    {{ $t('Login for conference participants') }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Auth>
</template>


I have already tried checking in the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware if the query has a code that comes from the login redirect OAuth Server, but as expected, logging out just leads to a loop again.
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if ($request->query('code')) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            } else {
                Auth::guard($guard)->logout();
                $request->session()->invalidate();
                $request->session()->regenerateToken();
                return redirect('/login');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}

Does anyone know how to solve the problem or is it perhaps a 1Password bug?

Which part is actually redirecting home here - the return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME); in your server-side handle method, or the location.href = route('test.home'); from your client-side message event handler?

This is triggered: return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
The popup doesn't even open and the loop already starts.

If the popup did not even open, then why would if ($request->query('code')) be true? The code is what you get back from the OAuth provider, when they redirect back to your application, is it not?

That was the attempt to allow only a valid login and not the one from 1Password. When you manually execute the pop-up and log in, everything works fine. When I deactivate 1Password, I can log in normally.

Now I am even more confused - what is 1password interfering with here? Are we not talking about the auth form provided inside the popup, by the OAuth provider? Do you have a "direct" login, that is completely handled by your system, as an alternative to the OAuth login, or what is the scenario here?

That's what confuses me a lot, too. No login is performed from the server side. I don't know how 1Password does it. Whether they're trying to hijack the session. I don't understand it. It just keeps endlessly trying to reach /home, which luckily redirects back to the login

AFAIK, these types of password manager plugins integrate themselves into login forms you might have on your page. But if you don't have one of those, then I can't see how "It seems to attempt to log in the user" would even work - log them into what, if no login form is provided to begin with? Are you pressing any buttons/icons 1password might have inserted into the page, or does it trigger this all on its own?
